# Need a sample of Jersey code using maven

Tags: rest, maven, jersey

Can anyone point me to a decent tutorial for using Maven with Jersey?
I looked at the Oracle tutorial but it is based on NetBeans and Glassfish (which I don't use).

More importantly, it does not seem to provide a web app deployment - where is my WEB-INF directory?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
See the below links, whichever one best suits your needs

Jersey samples:

https://github.com/fmucar/framework-samples
```